# WP Job Manager 132.2 “The link you followed has expired.” after previewed listing

Tags: php, wordpress

When I try to submit a new job listing, from the preview page, and click on “submit listing” we are now getting a bug that says “The link you followed has expired.” This happens on every version from 132.2+

I have followed the forum’s suggestions and have added the following code to our child theme’s job-preview.php page (right below the initial  tag) however, it is still not working. We are using the Sydney-child theme.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
/**
* Fires at the top of the preview job form.
*
* @since 1.32.2
*/
do_action( ‘preview_job_form_start’ );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

follow this step.

1. go to your job preview.php
2. search for where the form code is usually look like this